# How to create a sinusoidal wave of a line so that the start of the wave returns to being flat

Tags: processing

I know how to create a sinusoidal movement with particles as per the code below. What I would like to do however is to create an effect which is more of a ripple along a string. The idea is that a wave moves along a string but the section that is not currently in a wave returns to the zero position and doesn't undergo a further wave- ie just one wave passing down the line.

How do I amend the sinusoidal movement below to achieve this?

```java
int xspacing = 16;   // How far apart should each horizontal location be spaced
int w;              // Width of entire wave

float theta = 0.0;  // Start angle at 0
float amplitude = 75.0;  // Height of wave
float period = 500.0;  // How many pixels before the wave repeats
float dx;  // Value for incrementing X, a function of period and xspacing
float[] yvalues;  // Using an array to store height values for the wave

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  w = width+16;
  dx = (TWO_PI / period) * xspacing;
  yvalues = new float[w/xspacing];
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  calcWave();
  renderWave();
}

void calcWave() {
  // Increment theta (try different values for 'angular velocity' here
  theta += 0.02;

  // For every x value, calculate a y value with sine function
  float x = theta;
  for (int i = 0; i < yvalues.length; i++) {
    yvalues[i] = sin(x)*amplitude;
    x+=dx;
  }
}

void renderWave() {
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  // A simple way to draw the wave with an ellipse at each location
  for (int x = 0; x < yvalues.length; x++) {
    ellipse(x*xspacing, height/2+yvalues[x], 16, 16);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure exactly what you're going for. Drawing out some examples might help explain it better.

But the short answer to your question is: you'd change the height of the sin wave by modifying this line:

```
yvalues[i] = sin(x)*amplitude;
```

Right now every particle has the same amplitude, so it your wave has a uniform height. Instead, what you want to do is give each particle a different amplitude. Here's a very simple example:

```
yvalues[i] = sin(x) * x * 10;
```

This causes particles towards the left of the screen to have a smaller amplitude, and particles at the right of the screen to have a larger amplitude. In other words, the wave starts out flat and gets larger as it moves to the right.

What I would probably do is create a `Particle` class that encapsulates each particle's position, movement, and amplitude. Then I'd decrease the amplitude of each particle over time, maybe increasing it when the user clicks (or whatever event you want to spawn your waves).

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on creating classes in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/creating-classes).

Comment: Ok so the end result is that I want to create a n effect like I'm squeezing a tube from left to write by having two sinusoidal waves mirroring each other in the same direction. I'll give your method a work up unless you know of a preexisting example already

Comment: @SebastianZeki My approach should work fine for that.

Comment: I think what I want really is the sinusoidal way to pass through just once and then the particles to return to the neutral position. How would I do that? I tried using noloop() but of course that just stops everything so I guess I want to stop it after the wave has passed the end of the line..

Comment: @SebastianZeki Like I said, I would create a `Particle` class that encapsulates each particle's position, movement, and amplitude. Then I'd decrease the amplitude over time.